# Routing from childs components "blinks" my navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement the routing for my application. When I'm routing from the firsts components in the tree, it's Ok (like app-menu or search), but when I'm in childs components (event-item or sticker), my app blinks : it displays the good page a few seconds (in a good way, I mean menus et search are well displayed (without all reloading), and result page in the router-outlet as wished), then go back to the root routing (so the resume one) with a whole-charging page. My route code is

```
(app.module.ts)

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent },
  { path: 'result/:searchType', component: ResultComponent },
  { path: '', component: ResumeComponent }
];
```

My structure :

```
app-root
    app-search
    app-menu
       app-event-item
    app-resume
       app-sticker
    app-profile
    app-result
```

Extract of HTML code of app-root component :

```
 <div>
   <div id="wrapper">

     <!-- Navigation -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">

       <app-menu></app-menu>

       <!-- TODO before supp -->

       <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
         <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
           <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
             <app-search></app-search>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>

     </nav>
     <div id="page-wrapper">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My code is simply  :

```
 <a routerLink="xxxx">[...]</a>
```

where xxxx is my routing page ; that's what I've done on every navigation links (a or button or whatever), the ones working and the ones don't. I didn't had a ts ou js code to manage the routing. I thought this could be enough for my needs.
For example :

```
<a routerLink="profile">[...]</a>
```

I tried adding a "/" thinking of a relative/absolute problem, but it don't seems to be my problem...
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found my error
The link was embedded in another "a" tag having an

```
<a href="#">
  [... some code]
     <a routerLink="xxxx">[...]</a>
  [... some code]
</a>
```

When I remove the href, it's all OK.

```
<a>
  [... some code]
     <a routerLink="xxxx">[...]</a>
  [... some code]
</a>
```